# Merge multiple queries excluding common results

Tags: t-sql, union, intersect

Data :

```
--Table 1 :
Id ZoneName
----------- --------
20011       Name1
10027       Name1
20011       Name1
20011       Name1
20011       Name1
20074       Name1
20011       Name2
20011       Name2
10059       Name3
20011       Name2
```

Query :

```
 Select Top 2 [Id] From Table1 -- First Query
    WHERE ZoneName = 'Name1'
    UNION
    SELECT Top 1 [Id] from Table1 -- Second Query
    WHERE ZoneName = 'Name1'
    UNION
    SELECT Top 1 [Id] from Table1 -- Third Query
    WHERE ZoneName = 'Name1'
```

Result :

```
Id
-----
20011
```

Expected Result :

```
20011
10027
20074
```

From the above query I need 3 results from each query that do NOT overlap each other, in this case the expected result should contain the top 2 for query 1 i.e. 20011 and 10027 and for the next top 1 it should exclude those 2 results and return 20074 for query 2.

Note : I have used a single WHERE condition for this example, however in the actual query each of the query has different Where conditions, and could end up having same / different result from the query above itself.

Comment: But that is the behavior of UNION.  If you want duplicates then you need to UNION ALL.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx

Comment: I actually do not want duplicates between any of them but how do I exclude something from query 2 which has already been returned for query 1?

Comment: Added more explanation

Comment: Added actual data and more explanation !

Comment: Except will not work because it will exclude the result between Query 1 and 2 and return me no results, can you modify your answer to be more specific ? Thanks !

Comment: That is way different then the original post of selects from three different tables.  Your expectation of the current queries is flawed and I give up.

Comment: The "flaw" is what needs correction - but thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know If you are searching to query distinct Id's for a particular ZoneName then this may work out

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ZoneName="Name1"
```